# CentOS 6.4 server no internet connection

Tags: linux, networking, internet, centos, troubleshooting

I just installed CentOS 6.4 on my server. I've tried running `sudo yum update` and got the output `Could not retrieve mirrorlist...snip...error was 14: PYCURL ERROR 6 - "Couldn't resolve host 'mirrirlist.centos.org'"`. I can't ping to other computers on the same lan or sites such as google. I just started using CentOS about 10 minutes ago and have no experience with any Unix system before this.

Any help to get me guided would be great. How do I connect to the internet?

UPDATE: Will post the results of `ifconfig`.

```
eth0
Link encap:Ethernet HWaddr 00:13:D4:DD:14:D8
inet6 addr: fe80::213:d4ff:fedd:14d8/64 Scope:Link
UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST MTU:1500 Metric:1
RX packets:120 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
TX packets:4 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000
RX bytes:12210 (11.9KiB) TX bytes:344 (344.0 b)
Interrupt:22 Base Address:0x8000

lo
Link encap:Local Loopback
inet addr:127.0.0.1 Mask:255.0.0.0
inet6 addr: ::1/128 Scope:Host
UP LOOPBACK RUNNING MTU:16436 Metric:1
RX packets:18 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
TX packets:18 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
collisions:0 txqueuelen:0
RX bytes:1512 (1.4 KiB) TX bytes:1512 (1.4 KiB)
```

Comment: Please post the output of `ifconfig`.

Comment: Done, see the update

Comment: Please, any help would suffice. I'm a complete beginner and hardly know what I'm doing

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IP(v4) on eth0 interface is not configured on your host.
Configure it according [dhcp](http://www.centos.org/docs/5/html/Deployment_Guide-en-US/s1-dhcp-configuring-client.html) or
[static](http://www.centos.org/docs/5/html/Deployment_Guide-en-US/s1-networkscripts-interfaces.html).

After this make sure that your host can resolve mirrirlist.centos.org server.

```
~ # host mirrirlist.centos.org
```

Check /etc/resolv.conf content. It has to contain correct nameserver. Example :

```
~ # cat /etc/resolv.conf 
nameserver 192.168.1.1
```

Comment: The links are dead.